# Telegram bot API - Inline bot getting Error 400 while trying to answer inline query

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram-bot

I have a problem coding a bot in Python that works with the [new inline mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inline-mode).

The bot gets the query, and while trying to answer, it receives **error 400**.

Here is a sample of data sent by the bot at this time:

```
{
    'inline_query_id': '287878416582808857',
    'results': [
        {
            'type': 'article', 
            'title': 'Convertion', 
            'parse_mode': 'Markdown', 
            'id': '287878416582808857/0', 
            'message_text': 'blah blah'
        }
    ]
}
```

I use [requests](http://fr.python-requests.org/en/latest/api.html) library in to make requests, and here is the line that does it in the code:

```
requests.post(url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot%s%s" % (telegram_bot_token, "/answerInlineQuery"), data = myData)
```

With `myData` holding the data described in the sample.

Can you help me solve this, please?

Comment: [HTTP Error 400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) is a _Bad Request_ error, this can have many reasons. What other information can you provide?

Comment: I don't know what it comes from. Provided the request, the data I send and a link to the API. Sincerely, I don't know why I get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it is because you haven't JSON-serialized the `results` parameter.

```
import json

results = [{'type': 'article', 
            'title': 'Convertion', 
            'parse_mode': 'Markdown', 
            'id': '287878416582808857/0', 
            'message_text': 'blah blah'}]

my_data = {
    'inline_query_id': '287878416582808857',
    'results': json.dumps(results),
}

requests.post(url="https://api.telegram.org/bot%s%s" % (telegram_bot_token, "/answerInlineQuery"), 
              params=my_data)
```

Note that I use `params` to supply the data.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. I didn't mark it as solution yesterday because I was still getting **Err 400** because of my bad connection. What was happening after your solution is that the `inline_query_id` was expiring before the bot finishes the work and sends the results. I also figured a way to retrieve a description for the error from requests (`request.content`) and that helped me understand that `QUERY_ID_INVALID` was in description for the error 400 returned by the API.

Comment: I would like to mention that I was using exactly this code but still kept getting 400 - QUERY_ID_INVALID. And after some headache I realised I was not fast enough in using the returned inline_query_id in my answer. I was testing my bot manually using Postman and I had to so some steps manually. I read some where that the inline_query_id is valid for 15 seconds   and I was sure I did everything within 15 seconds but still getting the error. Finally I really did it fast and I got 200 back :-).

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the correct response after doing some POC. I am using java `com.github.pengrad`.

Below the code.

```
GetUpdatesResponse updatesResponse = bot.execute(new GetUpdates());
List updates = updatesResponse.updates();
for(Update update:updates){
    InlineQuery inlineQuery = update.inlineQuery();
    System.out.println(update);
    System.out.println(inlineQuery);
    System.out.println("----------------");
    if(inlineQuery!=null) {
        InlineQueryResult r1 = new InlineQueryResultPhoto("AgADBQADrqcxG5q8tQ0EKSz5JaZjzDWgvzIABL0Neit4ar9MsXYBAAEC", "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot230014106:AAGtWr8xUCqUy8HjSgSFrY3aCs4IZs00Omg/photo/file_1.jpg", "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot230014106:AAGtWr8xUCqUy8HjSgSFrY3aCs4IZs00Omg/photo/file_1.jpg");
        BaseResponse baseResponse = bot.execute(new AnswerInlineQuery(inlineQuery.id(), r1)
            .cacheTime(6000)
            .isPersonal(true)
            .nextOffset("offset")
            .switchPmParameter("pmParam")
            .switchPmText("pmText"));
        System.out.println(baseResponse.isOk());
        System.out.println(baseResponse.toString());
        System.out.println(baseResponse.description());
    }
}
```

Below the console output:

```
Update{update_id=465103212, message=null, edited_message=null, inline_query=InlineQuery{id='995145139265927135', from=User{id=231700283, first_name='Manabendra', last_name='Maji', username='null'}, location=null, query='hi', offset=''}, chosen_inline_result=null, callback_query=null}

InlineQuery{id='995145139265927135', from=User{id=231700283, first_name='Manabendra', last_name='Maji', username='null'}, location=null, query='hi', offset=''}

true
BaseResponse{ok=true, error_code=0, description='null'}
null
```

And I am getting proper response in my mobile telegram app also.